# Working with a two-variable function with one input fixed

Tags: function-construction

Here's what I know how to do:

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 4 x + 4
Ordering[f /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

This will evaluate f at each point and rank their sizes.

Here's what I really have:

```
g[x_,y_]:=(x-y)^2 - 4(x-y)+4
```

I'd like to do the same type of `Ordering` as above but with a fixed value of `y`. Currently, I'm doing it this way

```
yfixed=0;
f[x_]:=g[x,yfixed]
Ordering[f /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

There's got to be a better way without creating the `f` function. Something like `Ordering[g[_,0]/@{1,2,3}]`. What's the technique here that I don't know?

Comment: `Ordering[Function[x, g[x, yfixed]] /@ {1, 2, 3}]`?

Comment: @J. M.: beat me to it. Unfortunately, I already posted the answer! (Without paying attention to the fact that you'd already commented, of course. Does that mean I should remove it? I'm not sure of the etiquette, here.)

Comment: It's good that you wrote an answer, @march (I have upvoted it), but I believe OP will benefit greatly from you showing versions with and without `Slot`. :)

Comment: I'm new here, @J. M., so I'm unsure of etiquette in general. Thanks for the recommendation: I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated to provide more details (per a suggestion in the comments). In addition, the implementation using `Outer` was wrong**

A simple extension of what you've written will do the trick:

```
Ordering[Function[x,g[x,yFixed]] /@ {1,2,3}]
```

or more simply,

```
Ordering[g[#,yFixed]& /@ {1,2,3}]
```

where `g[#,yFixed]&` is essentially shorthand for `Function[x,g[x,yFixed]]`.

The reason your original idea doesn't work is that `Map` (or `/@`) applies the left-hand side to each element of the right-hand in a literal fashion. For instance, the first element of the list is `g[_,0][1]`. In this case, `g[_,0]` gets evaluated first by plugging in `_` for `x` and `0` for `y`. The resulting expression is then applied to `1`, yielding `(4 - 4 _ + _^2)[1]`, which is a very strange expression.

Alternatively, you could use `Outer`, although maybe this is overkill for this problem. On the other hand, it would allow you to do many values of `y` at once, by replacing the third argument of `Outer` with the list of `y`'s and mapping `Ordering` over the result. For your example:

```
Ordering[Outer[g,{1,2,3},{yFixed}]]
```

`Outer` supplies all pairs of elements---the first from the first list, and the second from the second---as inputs to `g` and forms a list. If you have a list `ys={0,4}`, you could do

```
Ordering/@ Transpose[Outer[g,{1,2,3},ys]]
```